# Why I can't put a property name in setter instead of "value" keyword?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties

When I assign a value in the setter through the `value` keyword, it works. But why it doesn't work when I try to assign the value through the name of the property, which should hold the same assigned value?

In the following example, I use `value` keyword in setter, and it works just fine and I get the expected output -

```
private int i = 1;
public int prop
{ 
    get { return i; }
    set { i = value }
}

public void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine(i)
}

static void Main ()
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.prop = 5;
    Console.WriteLine(p.prop);   // outputs 5
    p.Print();                   // outputs 5
}
```

But in the following example, I use property name `prop` instead of `value` keyword, and it doesn't assign the new value to the `i` variable -

```
private int i = 1;
public int prop
{ 
    get { return i; }
    set { i = prop }
}

public void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine(i)
}

static void Main ()
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.prop = 5;
    Console.WriteLine(p.prop);   // outputs 1
    p.Print();                   // outputs 1
}
```

So, what is the difference? Why I can't use name of the property, which should hold new value, instead of `value` keyword?

Comment: Cause properties in C# are designed [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) - "The `value` keyword is used to define the value being assigned by the set accessor."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumption about your property -

> which should hold the same assigned value

is basically wrong. Your property itself is not holding any value at all, it just returns the value of the variable `i`.

To get a clear picture, keep in mind that C# properties are just syntactic sugar over a pair of methods, and for your property -

```
public int prop
{ 
    get { return i; }
    set { i = value }
}
```

two methods will be generated behind the scene, which look like -

```
public int get_prop()
{
    return this.i;
}

public void set_prop(int value)
{
    this.i = value;
}
```

As you can see, the `value` keyword in your property represents a generalized name for the parameter that is passed from outside when you try to set value to a property. So, when you do something like -

```
p.prop = 5;
```

basically the `set_prop` method gets called with 5 as the value for the parameter `value`.

Now, when you are trying to use your property like -

```
public int prop
{ 
    get { return i; }
    set { i = prop }
}
```

the generated methods will look like -

```
public int get_prop()
{
    return this.i;
}

public void set_prop(int value)
{
    this.i = this.prop;
}
```

and as you can see, this code is totally ignoring the value of the `value` parameter passed from outside.

Your code is still setting the value though. It is calling the get method (which returns the value of `i`) and setting the already set value of `i` to `i` again. It is just not making any use of the value that has been passed to it.

Answer (score 8):

Because it's not the same. This setter:

```
public int prop
{ 
    get { return i; }
    set { i = prop; } // here
}
```

Will read the *current* value of `prop` by calling its getter at the line above it. The keyword `value` is specifically meant to obtain the value-to-be-set, you can't exchange that for the property's name, because that means something else.

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties#the-set-accessor):

> The set accessor resembles a method whose return type is void. **It uses an implicit parameter called `value`**, whose type is the type of the property.
>
> [...]
>
> When you assign a value to the property, the set accessor is invoked by using an argument that provides the new value.

Answer (score -1):

"value" is the paramater that is passed in.

prop = 10 will pass in a value of 10 into the setter which you can then grab and assign to your own variable "i"

If you don't use "value" your setter doesn't really do anything.